# php date_diff issue. getting blank result

Tags: php

I am running php 5.3.5 on my local wamp setup. I am running a simple code.

```
echo "<br/>DEBUGGING";
echo "<br/>===========";
echo "<br/>Date: ".$date;
echo "<br/>Lead Days: ".$lead_days;
echo "<br/>Date diff: ".var_dump(date_diff((int)$date, (int)$lead_days))." difference";
```

But the output is:

```
DEBUGGING
===========
Date: 2012-08-31
Lead Days: 2012-09-05

boolean false


Date diff: difference
```

date_diff seems to return false. I have tried it without var_dump and without int casting, but it always comes blank, however it works if I upload to my webserver. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't case date string to int.

`date_diff` need two `DateTime` objects as parameter, and return a `DateInterval` object.

```
$interval = date_diff(new DateTime($date), new DateTime($lead_days));
echo "<br/>Date diff: " . $interval->d . " days difference";
```